# Fully custom lightbox in dhtmlxGantt

Tags: javascript, ajax, dhtmlx, gantt-chart

**Hi there,**

I'm looking at using [dhtmlxgantt](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/) as a way of building up an itinerary i.e. you add items at specific days throughout a period (most likely 2 weeks)... However, there are quite a few extra variables that I need to store along with the standard info of dates etc. There are a series of 4 dropdowns which populate the next one via AJAX.

I know I can add [custom controls](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__default_edit_form.html) into the lightbox but these will not work via AJAX when the previous dropdown is changed. I was hoping that I'd be able to make a fully custom lightbox which then passes everything back to dhtmlxGantt but I can't seem to find away...

It looks like it's possible in the scheduler product (http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/02_customization/16_custom_form.html) can we do the same with Gantt?

Thanks in advance,

**Adam.**

Answer (score 1):

You can just redefine **gantt.showLightbox** method and show your form from there. And then use public API to save changes - [gantt.addTask](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_addtask.html), [gantt.updateTask](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_updatetask.html), [gantt.deleteTask](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_deletetask.html)

Here is a crude example:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/snippet/5e134aa1